# Vim's errorformat is ignored

Tags: vim, errorformat

I have a problem with Vim's (v7.3) errorformat. Trying to set it to extract my C errors into quickfix. The error pattern is probably well-known:

```
<file>:<line>:<column>: error: <message>
```

I am setting this errorformat:

```
:set errorformat=%f:%l:%c:\ error:\ %m
```

Then I run `:make` (and I have a modified `:makeprg` too). But the `errorformat` setting does not work. It's like it's completely ignored, since the quickfix is filled up with more or less the entire compilation log file (not only errors).

I even try to set the errorformat to some nonsense, like this:

```
:set errorformat=sdkljfsldkfjsdlsdsd
```

Still, same result. The quickfix is filled up with hundreds of lines.

Am I missing some magic turn on/off the `errorformat` setting?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Have you set a compiler via `:compiler`? (See `:h  You can use `<c-d>` or `<tab>` for completion. Personally I would try `:set errorformat=%f:%l:%c:\ %trror:\ %m` to make sure the error type is set properly.

Comment: Thanks Peter! It works now! :-)  I had completely overlooked `:compiler`. I now set it to "gcc", and I automatically get a nice `errorformat` string. And the errors ends up in quickfix as I want them too. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Vim comes with many `'makeprg'` and `'errorformat'` settings that are already defined for different compilers/linters. To use these settings use the `:compiler` command. You can use tab-completion (or `<c-d>` to list out the options) to select one of the predefined definitions.

```
:compiler gcc
```

For more help see:

```
:h :compiler
:h 'makeprg'
:h 'errorformat'
:h errorformat
```